# Could Kana really tell Shinichi's Migi apart from the other Parasytes, or was she just delusional?

Tags: parasyte

In episode 12, Kana tells Shinichi that she can tell Migi's emissions apart from the other Parasytes. However, she is shown as being on "cloud nine" for Shinichi - going as far as wrapping his hair around her finger like an engagement ring, and

> near the end of the episode, she mistakes another Parasyte for Shinichi in the ruined building, leading to her death.

Since Migi states that her powers are increasing, it could be possible that she would be able to tell the Parasytes apart in the future. However, her death cut that development short.

Was she really able to tell Shinichi apart from the other Parasytes, or was she just delusional? Does the manga reveal anything about this?

Comment: I strongly suspect she was delusional - not even Migi, itself a parasyte, can tell one parasyte from another. What are the odds that Kana, a mere human, could?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR**: It is possible, though the manga is never conclusive about that.

@senshin I think Migi is able to tell one parasite from another, at least that is the case for a certain parasite. The proof is given on Page 194 in Volume 9 of the manga:

> [image: Migi could tell Gotou from other parasites]

So if Kana can reach the level of Migi in detecting and differentiating the signals emitted by the parasites, then she would probably be able to tell Shinichi and Migi from the other parasites. Kana demonstrated her potential with her incredible sensing ability on Page 75 in Volume 5 of the manga:

> [image: Kana sensed 4 or 5 out of 8 parasites]

And on Pages 115 and 120 in Volume 5 of the manga, we saw that her powers have evolved.

> [image: Kana emitted a signal][image: Migi told Shinichi about Kana's signal]

Then there is her dream, in which Shinichi is clearly distinguishable from the other parasites. Conclusion: it does seem promising that Kana might eventually be able to tell Shinichi and Migi from the other parasites had she not rushed to her death at the hands of a parasite when her powers were still immature.

Comment: Kind of depends....while at the time we don't know what Gotoh actually is, i.e. NOT your average parasyte, it's possible that normal parasytes are indisguishable, where as abnormal parasytes like Pre-Op Migi and Gotoh have differences. I.e. Migi being weaker in his dormant state (since they're sensing the pieces in Shinichi) or Gotoh who has a MUCH stronger signal.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly doubt that she would ever be able to tell apart two regular parasistes like Uragami never found differences between them - with one exception:

> Gotou is different because he contains several parasites and for this reason has a way stronger signal. Sleeping Migi is different too, he has a weaker signal, but still Kana couldn't tell that Migi was sleeping when Shinichi told her everything.

But, getting strong, her powers could reach the point where she could even sense human's brain waves and then she'd become able to tell apart Migi/Shinichi from regular parasites and may even tell apart Shinichi from other humans...

> because of the parasite cells in his body and brain.